# "the research literature " - Meaning

Tags: meaning

what does " **the research literature** " means ?

> We know from ***the research literature*** that the more you use social media, the more likely you are to feel lonely or isolated.

Comment: What about it don't you understand? "Research" and "literature" are well-defined terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Literature** in this context is not used in its most common sense of "fiction and novels", but in a slightly more technical sense.  From the OED:

> 4. (A body of) non-fictional books and writings published on a particular subject.

Thus, the "research literature" refers collectively to the publications that have been published as a result of research on a particular subject.